# JAXB only shows JAXBContext.newInstance() with unmarshelling overloaded methods

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

i am in middle of java implementation and JAXBContext only have

```
public static javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext newInstance(java.lang.String p1) { }

public static javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext newInstance(java.lang.String p1, java.lang.ClassLoader p2) { }
```

methods which are using for genarate classes from xml. i am using jdeveloper 10g with jaxb from jdk 1.5 . How to solve this problem?

Comment: What problem? `newInstance()` has 5 overloads in Java 6. What were you expecting to be different?

Comment: no i am sorry java 1.5 and not it only have 2 overloaded newInstance()

Comment: I don't understand your issue!

Comment: i cant give the class name as parameter because i only have these 2 implementations on my jaxb . they can  only  use for unmarshelling from xml to class

Comment: `JAXBContext` does not exist in Java 5 SE.

Comment: well it does but with only 2 overloaded methods. java version 1.5.0_05 to be precise

Comment: @Andreas is there are anyway of putting an eternal jar and ignore the jar from jdk to get all 5 methods

Comment: You still haven't said what your problem is. You specify the `contextPath`, i.e. the package name of your binding classes, and it will find them for you.

Comment: i have to marshal a class to xml using java 1.5 . but in the JAXBContext  only have 2 newInstance() methods that i have written in the question . my question is how to get all 5 methods . or by pass the jdk's JAXBContext   and put external jar file to get newer version of jaxb.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway I found out the issue. The JAXB version of java 1.5 only supports unmarshall. so it only shows the unmarshalling overloaded methods. it was fixed after i compile with java 1.6 with JDK integrated JAXB jars.